# Convert Fading Black Separator From "-webkit-gradient" To "linear-gradient"

Tags: html, css, gradient, linear-gradients

I have a gradient that I am currently using that I would like converted from -webkit to the default linear-gradient. I have tried using all of the CSS generating tools online to import the code in order to see the other browser specific variants, but for some reason when I import the code the gradient in the results section just becomes white.

```
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 0, from(white), to(white), color-stop(50%, black));
```

[JSFiddle Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/Hybridx24/7Lcanuwx/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
.sexy_line {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, white, black, white);
}
```

See this [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) for more info on linear gradients.

**DEMO**

```css
.sexy_line { 
    margin: 25px 0;
    height: 1px;
    background: black;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, white, black, white);
}
```

```html
<div class="sexy_line"></div>
```

Comment: Perfect! I am going to give you the Completed Answer check as soon as the 5 minute timer passes :) One more question though - is it possible to easily change the fade from black to transparent (instead of white)?

Comment: Yes, just change `white` to `transparent`

Comment: Ended up guessing that one through but thanks again!

Comment: @Hybrid No problem :)

Answer (score 1):

I use [ColorZilla's Gradient Editor](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) **all** the time since it spits out cross browser code and is super easy to use.

Comment: Great recommendation, but in this case for some reason it did not support importing the code I provided :(

Comment: That's because of the word "to" - if you use this instead it will work:  `linear-gradient(right, white, black, white);`